# WebHook API execute two time with Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have issue with callback from Webhook Services trigger event from ACC, the problem is process execute two time.
Can I know the reason, this is my code :

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/forge/callback/webhook")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> WebhookCallback([FromBody] JObject body)
    {
        // catch any errors, we don't want to return 500
        try
        {
            string projectId = "b." + body["payload"]["project"];
            string versionId = body["resourceUrn"].ToString();
            string modelName = body["payload"]["name"].ToString();
            // remove 4 chars from the end (.rvt)
            modelName = modelName.Substring(0, modelName.Length - 4);
            string stormProcessState = body["payload"]["custom-metadata"]["storm:process-state"].ToString();


            // do you want to filter events??
            //if (eventType != "dm.version.added") return Ok();

            // your webhook should return immediately!
            // so can start a second thread (not good) or use a queueing system (e.g. hangfire)

            // starting a new thread is not an elegant idea, we don't have control if the operation actually complets...

           
            RevitDesignAutomate revitDesignAutomate = new RevitDesignAutomate(designAutomateConfiguration);
            string callback = "https://webhook.site/25ad18c1-2f09-4148-bfd1-2c8cd2418a9b";
            await revitDesignAutomate.ExecuteJob(projectId, versionId,modelName, callback);
           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // ALWAYS return ok (200)
        return Ok();
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean two times? Does the DM-related event get triggered twice or something else? Your code looks like for Data Management, not Design Automation.

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang, My design automatin execute everytime the user change from ACC and call back event  to this url. but the problem is callback event webhook execute 2 time, I hope this explain clearify your quesion.

Comment: What is the user change in your case? File upload, move?

Comment: In my case is user Publish with new version of Revit File in BIM 360

Comment: so, which WebHook event did you register, [dm.version.added](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/dm.version.added/), [dm.version.modified](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/dm.version.modified/)?

Comment: my hook now is dm.version.add

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chuongmep/5c4f18e98607bad2f81230bdcb422932

Comment: The above code seems only Design Automation, not related to the WebHook. Could you share the WebHook event callbacks you received with me? (Note. Please remove confidential info (project id, model urn, folder run and etc.)

Comment: it will be same like this : https://gist.github.com/chuongmep/d0d701a1ada31ac416d7a60890ab721d

Comment: gist.github.com/chuongmep/d0d701a1ada31ac416d7a60890ab721d is event `dm.version.modified`. Please ignore it.